Equilateral figure
Replace the question mark with the correct figure. Explain why it's correct.



Just want to say, this is not a standard progressive "IQ" puzzle.

I thought it's another one of these boring IQ puzzles. But this is truly brilliant! Well done.

@DmitryKamenetsky Thanks!

The missing figure is:

 

Because:

 If we look at the each figure as an incomplete hexagon, the lines that haven't been drawn spell the word HEXAGON:
 


Correct, well done!

Darn, I tried that, and thought it said HC.. and didn't look any further.

@JaapScherphuis that’s what I find great about his puzzles! I often get so close but just didn’t continue digging in that direction (usually I am way off when I read the answer with other puzzles). I feel he tries to get a perfect balance when it comes to difficulty so with any puzzle a sizeable number of people on PSE can get it within a couple of hours.
